# TCP/IP over SSL and silverlight

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I want to write a silverlight page which connects to a tcp/ip server. The server is layering ssl as well. The problem is I don't see a SSLStream in Silverlight.

Is this doable (I need the tcp/ip because this page will constantly get events from the server and no I don't want to poll, in fact I can't the server is third party)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok bottom line you cannot do this in Silverlight 3.0 apparently

Comment: per (deleted) non answers, this is apparently still not possible in Silverlight 4 or the announced-so-far bits of Silverlight 5?

Answer (score 0):

All communication in SL3 is over HTTP. You can communicate over HTTPS too.

SL4 supports TCP endpoints, but this is not available yet.

Best,
Mark

Comment: um SL3 has tcp endpoints I am pretty sure about that , but yeah there is no support for SSL over tcp\ip as I have discovered :-)
thanks

Comment: actually when I say tcp endpoints I mean you can open a socket so same difference :-)